# Are dictionaries faster than max comparisons

Tags: swift, performance, dictionary

I am working on a project where I need to get the final values from the user with as little latency as possible. User input is a series of sliders with integer values of 0-100 (so I don't care about anything outside that range).

Original setup is this (pseudocode, but project is written in swift 5 to run on macOS)

`final = max(a*A, b*B, s1*S1, s2*S2, ... s8*S8)`

lower case s values are guaranteed not to change in a speed-required way (but can be changed by user at any time, so can't be hardcoded)
if lower case a or b change, then this runs once.
if upper case A, B, or S change, then this runs 32 times.

Initial rethink:
`sValue =  max (s1*S1 ... s8*S8) //this would only run when one of the S values changes
final = max (a*A, b*B, sValue)`

Friend recommendation:
make a dictionary (hash table) with an array of Int as the key and the final value as the value; then do a lookup. This dictionary can be built at program launch (can stick it behind a loading screen)

So, which is the better solution from a performance perspective: dictionary with an array as keys or running the max function every time?
Or does anyone have any other recommendations?

Comment: *where I need to get the final values from the user with as little latency as possible*. Why? if you don't have another huge flaw, it shouldn't matter, as your user's neurones can't keep up anyway.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: This is running on 2009 hardware and caching it (option 2) did produce a noticeable speed increase.

Comment: As I said: if that is the case, you have another huge flaw.